# Increase listview's item height if inner textview's height takes up more than one line

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView component with the following item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_name"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_comment"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/event_listview_item_name"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The listview looks like:

[image]

But what if I wanted to use a long comment that takes up more than one line, and wraps?

In that case I get a result like:

[image]

Could you help me design my xml in such a way that listview items would have a flexible height? And if I use 2 or 3 lines for comment, will everything be visible correctly?

**UPDATED**

I have changed layout a little bit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_name"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_comment"
            android:layout_below="@+id/event_listview_item_name"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/event_listview_item_name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and now everything is almost done except one strange thing:

[image]

Why in case of multiline textview imageview is not centered vertical?

Comment: Here you just add android:layout_below attribute into your second textview and if you want display "....." for many long text then set singline and ellipsize properties.

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yes Andru I have checked your answer. It works. Thank you and other guys. Other answers are similar. One thing left. Why in case of multiline textview imageview is not centered vertical? Can you help?

Comment: Hi You try My Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi Please Try This Code Use LinearLayout Insted Of 
Relative Layout Relative layout always creat proble and 
when use it in different device it look different.
    -----------
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
                    android:layout_width="42dp"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:contentDescription="" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="dsjfdsssssfgufoioihgfhggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_comment"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/event_listview_item_name"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/event_listview_item_name"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `android:layout_below="@+id/event_listview_item_name"` for textview that you want to show below any view and remove `android:layout_alignBottom=""`.

Answer (score 1):

Add android:layout_below="@+id/event_listview_item_name" for second textview and remove android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"

Comment: Whats the difference between this answer and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the `layout_below` in the second TextView and remove **alignBottom** from there like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_name"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/event_listview_item_comment"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/event_listview_item_icon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/event_listview_item_name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add margin to the imageview that will increase your item size 
set the gravity for all of your view center-vertical to be

or but comment textview below the name textview

```
android:layout_below="@+id/event_listview_item_name"
```

and give it the id of name textview